# Using Z3Py With Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, python-2to3

### My Situation

I've installed Microsoft Z3 (`Z3 [version 4.3.0 - 64 bit]. (C) 2006`) and it's `pyc` binaries for Python2.

I've written an Python3 package which needs access to `z3` functionality.

In order to be able to use the `pyc` binaries with my Python3 package, I `decompyle` the `z3` binaries and applied `2to3`.

### My Problem

`Int('string')` doesn't work because Z3Py isn't able to handle the new `<class 'str'>` used as `'string'` argument:

```
>>> import z3; z3.Int('abc')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\bin\z3.py", line 2931, in Int
    return ArithRef(Z3_mk_const(ctx.ref(), to_symbol(name, ctx), IntSort(ctx).ast), ctx)
  File ".\bin\z3.py", line 72, in to_symbol
    return Z3_mk_string_symbol(_get_ctx(ctx).ref(), s)
  File ".\bin\z3core.py", line 1430, in Z3_mk_string_symbol
    r = lib().Z3_mk_string_symbol(a0, a1)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

### My Questions

- It's a little bit hacky to need to `decompyle` Z3's `*.pyc` files first. So, are there any Z3Py source codes available?
- Is there already an existing Z3Py port to Python3?
- Any other idea how to get **Z3Py to run with Python3**?

Thanks. - If anything's unclear, please leave a question comment.

Comment: Doesn't Z3 open sourced? http://z3.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Kabie Basically yes, but in that repository there aren't any Python3 compatible versions of the source codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unstable` (work-in-progress) has support for Python 3. This feature will be available in the next Z3 release (v4.3.2). In the meantime, you can build the `unstable` branch using the instructions found [here](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - But it seems like it **doesn't work together with the library** correctly. When calling a Python method of `z3`: `File ".\build\z3core.py", line 24, in lib raise Z3Exception("init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using Z3-python")` - Any idea?

Comment: This is error is usually generated when the Z3 shared object (*.so Linux, *.dylib OSX, or *.dll Windows) can't be found. You should include the shared object in you search path: on Linux you have to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. Another option is to invoke `init` with the full path to the Z3 shared object. Which platform are you using?

Comment: This project is thought to run on a Windows 7 environment. My object is currently located at `.\build\libz3.dll`. **Is there a special environment var I have** to set on Windows or is there anything else I can do to get Z3Py to find the object?

Comment: You should include the path to libz3.dll in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The path to `.\build` is actually included in `$PATH`. Any other reason why that exception could occur?

Comment: `.\build` is a relative path. Are you including the actual path in `PATH`. Have you tried to invoke `init('dir\libz3.dll')` in your python script? Another potential problem, if you are using a 32 bit python.exe, you must use a 32 bit DLL, even if you are using in 64 bit machine.

Comment: **(1)** I'm using the absolute path `C:\[PathTo]\build` in  `$PATH` – **(2)** `z3.init(libpath)` throws `File ".\Python\3.3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
  self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specific module could not be found`. – **(3)** I'm using `Python 3.3.0 [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` together with the `libz3.dll` built by `nmake`. – Thanks, hoping this piece of information makes sense to you.

Comment: I guess the `libz3.dll` is probably a 32 bit DLL. Could you try to compile the `libz3.dll` again using the (64-bit) instructions found here: http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Z3Py%20on%20Windows&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Another option is to use the precompiled DLL in the nightly builds for Windows 64-bit. This link has additional information: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/precompiled.html

Comment: Thanks - Now I'm using my self-compiled `unstable` build with the `libz3.dll` file replaced by the one from the `nightly` channel and I didn't encounter any problems so far.