# z3py installation

Tags: z3, smt, constraint-programming

I am having trouble getting z3 to work with Python. I am running Windows 7 64bit. I have downloaded 64bit Python 3.3.0 and 64bit z3 4.3.0. I have updated my PATH and PYTHONPATH to include the z3 \bin directory. However, when I try to use z3 in python I get the following error:

> > > from z3 import *
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: bad magic number in 'z3': b'\x03\xf3\r\n'

Does anyone know what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Z3 v4.3.0 does not support Python 3.3. We have to use Python 2.7 (or 2.6). The next official version will support Python 3.x. In the meantime, you can use the `unstable` (working-in-progress) branch. For more information see the following related question:

- [Using Z3Py With Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598669/using-z3py-with-python-3-3)