# Z3 v4.3.2 example.py execution error on Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: python, z3

I'm trying to build Z3 newest version (v4.3.2) on Mac OS X 10.10.2.

Downloading the latest source from http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/SourceControlFileDownload.ashx?he ProjectName=z3&changeSetId=cee7dd39444c9060186df79c2a2c7f8845de415b to follow the command in http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README.

```
CXX=clang++ CC=clang python scripts/mk_make.py
cd build
make
sudo make install
```

The build and installation seems to be OK, however, when I tried to run the example.py, I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = Real('x')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/z3.py", line 2774, in Real
    ctx = _get_ctx(ctx)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/z3.py", line 210, in _get_ctx
    return main_ctx()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/z3.py", line 205, in main_ctx
    _main_ctx = Context()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/z3.py", line 151, in __init__
    conf = Z3_mk_config()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/z3core.py", line 1036, in Z3_mk_config
    r = lib().Z3_mk_config()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/z3core.py", line 24, in lib
    raise Z3Exception("init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using Z3-python")
z3types.Z3Exception: init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using Z3-python
Exception AttributeError: "Context instance has no attribute 'lib'" in <bound method Context.__del__ of <z3.Context instance at 0x227800>> ignored
```

I added `export Z3_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` in the environment variables, and tried 64 bit python with `arch -x86_64 python example.py` to get the same results.

From [Using Z3Py With Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598669/using-z3py-with-python-3-3), I tried to copy the `libz3.a/dylib/java.dylib` files into the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, but without success.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Did you try setting `PYTHONPATH` to Z3's `bin` directory? You could also copy your `py`-file into Z3's `bin` directory (where `z3.pyc` etc. are), and run it from there. Does any of that help?

Comment: @Malte Schwerhoff: I  tried to set PYTHONPATH, but got the same results.

Comment: I had a similar problem on Win 7 x64, which apparently was due to using x86 Python with x64 Z3. The error disappeared after using x86 builds of both.

Comment: Yes, everything needs to be of the same bit-ness, i.e., Python 32-bit will refuse to load a 64-bit z3 and the other way around. In this particular case, did you also set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the z3 bin directory? Otherwise the system will not be able to find libz3.dylib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with 64 bit python that Mac OS supports.
From the hint [Executing python in 64 bit mode on Mac OS X 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185944/executing-python-in-64-bit-mode-on-mac-os-x-10-10/29187391#29187391), I installed python with `brew`, and now it works fine.

```
bin> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/python example.py 
sat
[y = 4, x = 2]
```