# Using Z3 with python in Visual studio 2013

Tags: z3

I installed the Python 2.7.10 64 bit. I downloaded the latest Z3 sources from https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3. I copied the folder z3-master in the Python27 folder. Then, I opened the Visual Studio 2013 command prompt and build the z3 using instructions provided on the same github page. Build was successful. I added the 'PHYTHONPATH c:\Python27\z3-master\build\z3lib.dll'. Now, when I run any example from visual studio python, it give me an error on the first line, i.e.,

from z3 import * : The error is 'no module named z3'

If I run the example from python shell, it give error 
"init(Z3_LIBRARY_PATH) must be invoked before using z3-python"

I don't see any bin folder inside z3-master or in the build folder.
How to use Z3py from within visual studio?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used the instructions given on the following link:
[Using Z3Py With Python 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598669/using-z3py-with-python-3-3)

Actually, only the last two instructions (comment) worked for me. That's instructions are as follow:

**Another option is to use the precompiled DLL in the nightly builds for Windows 64-bit. This link has additional information: research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/blog/2013/02/15/… –  Leonardo de Moura Mar 25 '13 at 23:35

Thanks - Now I'm using my self-compiled unstable build with the libz3.dll file replaced by the one from the nightly channel and I didn't encounter any problems so far. –  fdj815**

So, I simply went to the link, clicked on the "Nightly builds of Z3". Then click on the "Go to the Z3 Downloads page". Then, I downloaded the 64 bit pre-compiled zip file. Unzip it and added the path of bin folder to both 'PATH' & 'PYTHONPATH' environment variables. But in the Visual studio Python project, I still had to add 'PYTHONPATH' in the search paths of the project. It seems it doesn't automatically look into these environment variables.

Link to the nightly builds is:
http://leodemoura.github.io/blog.html

Comment: An environment record is per process and is inherited by children. If your Visual Studio process still carries a copy of the environment that doesn't contain your update, it won't see it.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for posting your solution here! Indeed, Visual Studio might want a per-project setting of PYTHONPATH and PATH. It should also work with a system-wide setting, but that's probably not what you want anyways.